# Settings and network missing, cannot connect to the internet

Tags: network-manager, settings, system-settings

Had to type this on a phone and it's sucking lately so i apologize for any typoes/autocorrect snafus i miss while proofing.

I have checked all hardware (the Ethernet port, the cables, etc).

A few days ago i suddenly had no internet on my desktop (running **18.04.1 LTS with Gnome)**, and my **GUI Settings** disappeared so i couldn't make any changes to my network settings.

I've looked around for help with the situation but can't seem to find someone with both these problems at once, it's either one or the other.

I've verified my `/etc/init.d/networking` and `network-manager` files and they seem to match all examples I've seen.

My problem is that i can't restore the **GUI Settings** without an internet connection, and i can't connect to the internet without my settings (i assume part 2, as i can't get far enough to test that theory).

I've checked my logs and such and all get is

> Failed to start network-manager

but nothing else helpful.  If i try to reinstall or just install the network manager or the gui settings it just does it's thing then tries to contact my PPAs, even though i disabled them all and selected to use the dvd instead.

I'm hoping someone else has had this problem and can help, or who is talented enough to just know the fix.  It's my desktop which makes it hard to post dumps and post them, same with screenshots, as i can only use my cell to access this site, so please only request those if it's really necessary.

Re-installing the OS is going to be an absolute last option as i have a lot of things installed with very customized settings throughout (i never changed the network settings if that thought just popped up to you, it's been untouched since my original install last April).  I know i can backup before, and restore settings after, a reinstall but i never know what files to backup, or have a complete list of what i have personally installed as many items are background. (Oh, and I've not installed, uninstalled, or altered any programs on the system since the new year, so i can't blame that either.) And I'm sure I'd just restore the same network settings as i never know if and what to restore after a reinstall, and then the loop States again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can set you network using legacy way - by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. 
First you need to list all your interfaces by `ip a`.
Then, you need to edit interface that you normally use for Internet connection. 
It should look like that:

```
*name of your interface* auto
iface *name of your interface* inet dhcp
```

Then you can do 
`ip link set name of your interface down && ^down^up`

That will reboot you interface and enable configuration.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Have me back internet so now i can restore my settings gui

Comment: Does not help.  After reboot the network is gone again.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with this and I went into the grub menu and selected a previous image to get this working

Comment: Ironically probably the most obvious answer and I hadn't tried it, thank you.  I'll give it a go and we'll see.

Comment: This didn't work :-(

Comment: See this post in Ubuntu Forums: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364474

Comment: @Carlos Dagorret thanks for that link, it's something in going to keep for any future issues I have, it was an interesting read.