# Missing settings pannel + missing internet control (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, settings, nvidia-settings

I am facing a very annoying problem. This week, I saw two things waking up on my Ubuntu when I woke up.

1. I no longer have "settings" graphical interfaces ...
2. I no longer have internet.

One with the other, it's quite crippling.
I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa
kernel 5.4.0-86-generic.

My PC : Asus ROG Strix Scar II with Nvidia.
I am dual-booting with Windows 10.
I am the only user.
I specify that I really cannot access the settings, I no longer have the tab.

I looked for and carried out some commands which have not given anything yet, I will communicate the results to you anyway.

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ       
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 14.3
       information bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       nom logique: wlo1
       version: 10
       numéro de série: fc:77:74:c7:43:09
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-86-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:16 mémoire:a541c000-a541ffff

  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: eno2
       version: 15
       numéro de série: 04:92:26:1b:cb:3b
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       ressources : irq:18 portE/S:3000(taille=256) mémoire:a5204000-a5204fff mémoire:a5200000-a5203fff
```

```
Status du NetworkManager

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-09-24 22:52:45 CEST; 24min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 1550 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 1550 (code=exited, status=127)

sept. 24 22:52:45 kishikaisei systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
sept. 24 22:52:45 kishikaisei systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
sept. 24 22:52:45 kishikaisei systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
sept. 24 22:52:45 kishikaisei systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sept. 24 22:52:45 kishikaisei systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


sheitak@kishikaisei:~$ journalctl -xe

-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit NetworkManager.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
sept. 24 23:17:52 kishikaisei systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
sept. 24 23:17:52 kishikaisei systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) NetworkManager.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
```

The files in NetworkManager and netplan look fine, based on all the problems I have read.

**My Problem** : I want to find my settings panel. I want to be able to connect to the internet again.

I must say that I am very close to reinstalling Ubuntu ... But I leave a chance before for the expertise of the community. What an obscure problem .. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my problem. I explain if anyone encounters the same concerns.

Unfortunately I can't wait, I need Ubuntu to be available very soon. I found a very interesting post that I recommend following if you are in the same situation : [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115581/settings-and-network-missing-cannot-connect-to-the-internet)

Although nothing worked for me, I followed [the reinstall procedure](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/reinstallation_ubuntu) for Ubuntu 20.04. Chapter **"Method 1 : Reinstall without touch "/home""**.

By following this exactly, I was able to find Ubuntu exactly as it was, with my folders, files and configurations.

Only need to install packages disappeared with apt-get. They will revert to the configuration you left before the reinstallation.

So I once again have access to the settings application and to the connection settings and I found the internet.

Thank you very much for your answers @guiverc